# Create right responsive arrow

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I need to create right arrow. See the images below:

[image]

[image]

The problem is that the div has a variable width because of .row (Bootstrap). How can I give the arrow (:after element) the appropriate width so that it will still be responsive?

My work so far:

https://jsfiddle.net/rafaelvida/8oLxz7mv/11/

```css
.bg-orange {
    background: #C57B10;
}


.border-orange {
    border: 3px solid #C57B10;
}

.cursor-pointer {
    cursor: pointer;
}

.small-sm {
    font-size: 70%!important;
}

.chat-atual {
    border: 3px solid #C57B10!important;
    position: relative;
}   

.chat-atual:after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    right: -4%;
    bottom: 5%;
    background-color: #C57B10;
    padding-bottom: 18%;
    width: 18%;
    transform-origin: 70% 0%;
    transform: rotate(-45deg);
    z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="row w-25 bg-orange text-uppercase py-1 px-3 mt-4 cursor-pointer link-chat chat-atual" id="chat-geral" data-para="0">
  <div class="col-2 my-auto p-lg-2 p-1">
    <i class="fa fa-user"></i>
  </div>
  <div class="col-10 my-auto p-lg-2 p-1 pl-3">
    <small class="small-sm">
      <strong>Chat geral</strong>
    </small>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please post your work till now

Comment: Provide code examples so we can help you more effectively.

Comment: My work: https://jsfiddle.net/rafaelvida/8oLxz7mv/11/

Comment: @Rafael: can you explain the outcome you want to achieve? Please explain more what your meaning of the arrow being responsive?

Comment: The right arrow appears different according screen size.